# How to pass flags to node scripts based on node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command

I have following two scripts in my project (`package.json` file) -

```
   "scripts": {
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
```

On my local, the node version usually defaults to v17 which I use across the project (monorepo). But when I deploy the storybook, the max node version available is 16.

If I don't pass the `openssl-legacy-provider` flag, I get error in my local dev.

If I do pass the flag, the deployment shows error as the flag is not supported.

Is there a way to optionally pass the flag based on node version?

Comment: You certainly could run a shell script to detect the node version and then call the correct command, but ideally you should be using the same version of Node wherever you project is run. I suggest making your local match the deployed, as otherwise you will run into breaking changes that might not always be fixable. I recommend using [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your local node version

Comment: Why not use v16 locally?

Comment: that is what I decided to do finally. I just didn't want to switch between v17 and v16 when moving across the monorepo.